# What is the main clause here?

Tags: grammar, clauses, subjects, subordinate-clauses, predicate

> *He has a chain [which is made of gold]*.
>
> The sentence has two clauses: a main clause (italicised) and a
>   subordinate clause (bracketed) embedded within it, each having its own
>   subject and predicate. In the main clause, **he** is subject and **has
>   a chain which is made of gold** is predicate. In the subordinate
>   clause, **which** is subject and **is made of gold** is predicate.

I have seen the above explanation of clause in an English forum. Is it correct? Can I also say that **He has a chain** is also a clause with **He** as its subject and **has a chain** as its predicate?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. "He has a chain" is a clause. It is called a main clause or an independent clause. As you stated, "He" is the subject and "has a chain" is the predicate.

Comment: "He has a chain" is a clause on its own, but it is not a clause within the OP's sentence. Like the person he quotes says, the predicate of the clause which *he* is the Subject of is *has a chain which is made of gold*.

Comment: @Araucaria. Hi, Thanks for the reply. what is OP?

Comment: @Sivani Oh, OP = Original Poster. This is the person who asked the question, or wrote the post. So in this case the OP is you! :-)